# Laravel: ORM retrieving data ordered by related table

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I am creating simple messenger for Laravel 4, with fuctionality pretty same as Facebook messenger. I have problem making Eloquent query to list latest messages with threads for currently logged user.

**Consider I have the following DB tables for messenger (there is also users table):**

```
+-----------+ +--------------+ +----------------+ +----------------+ +-----+ 
|threads    | |thread_users  | |messages        | |messages_status | |users|
+-----------+ +--------------+ +----------------+ +----------------+ +-----+
|id         | |id            | |id              | |id              | |id   |
|title      | |thread_id     | |thread_id       | |user_id         | |name |
|created_at | |user_id       | |sender_id (user)| |message_id      | +-----+
|deleted_at | |created_at    | |content         | |deleted_at      |
+-----------+ |deleted_at    | |created_at      | +----------------+
              +--------------+ +----------------+
```

**DB explanation:**

When user writes first message he creates thread. All users added to thread are listed in thread_users table. Message submitted to thread are stored in messages table, which is linked to messages_status table where i'm storing info if user deleted particular message from thread for his account.

**Laravel models (i have removed SoftDeletingTrait to make it clear):**

```
class threads extends \Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'threads';

     public function participants() {
         return $this->hasMany('messengerThreadUsers', 'thread_id', 'id');
     }

     public function userParticipation() {
         return $this->hasOne('threadUsers', 'thread_id', 'id')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
     }

     public function messages() {
         return $this->hasMany('message', 'thread_id', 'id');
     }

     public function lastMessage() {
         return $this->hasOne('message', 'thread_id', 'id')->latest();
     }
}

class threadUsers extends \Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'thread_users';
}

class message extends \Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'messages';

     public function statuses() {
         return $this->hasMany('messageStatus', 'message_id', 'id');
     }

     public function thread() {
         return $this->hasOne('threads', 'id', 'thread_id');
     }
}

class messageStatus extends \Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'messages_status';

     public function message() {
         return $this->hasOne('message', 'id', 'message_id');
     }

     public function thread() {
         return $this->hasOne('threads', 'id', 'thread_id');
     }
}
```

**Now i want to make query that return 5 most recent messages (ordered by message creation date) together with threads, for currently logged user, but where message_status.deleted_at is NULL.**

So far i've got this:

```
$this->threads->select(\DB::raw('threads.*'))
     ->with('lastMessage')
     ->has('userParticipation')
     ->join('messages', 'messages.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
     ->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'DESC')
     ->paginate(5);
```

But it keeps returning me dupicate threads. In DB i have 2 threads:

1. thread #1 have 2 messages in it
2. thread #2 have 1 message in it

---

output below:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 10
      'title' => string 'THREAD 1' (length=8)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-07-06 14:20:03' (length=19)
      'last_message' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 11
          'sender_id' => int 12
          'thread_id' => int 10
          'content' => string 'MSG 1 in thread 1' (length=129)
          'created_at' => string '2015-07-07 19:36:52' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 10
      'title' => string 'THREAD 1' (length=8)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-07-06 14:20:03' (length=19)
      'last_message' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 11
          'sender_id' => int 12
          'thread_id' => int 10
          'content' => string 'MSG 1 in thread 1' (length=129)
          'created_at' => string '2015-07-07 19:36:52' (length=19)
  2 => 
     array (size=5)
      'id' => int 10
      'title' => string 'THREAD 2' (length=8)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-07-06 14:25:13' (length=19)
      'last_message' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 11
          'sender_id' => int 12
          'thread_id' => int 10
          'content' => string 'MSG 1 in thread 2' (length=129)
          'created_at' => string '2015-07-07 19:56:22' (length=19)
```

Comment: You're missing `groupBy`

Comment: Oh my god! Sorry for my inattention, it's working now :) many thanks JarekTkaczyk